# Windows 10, disable EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled by default

Tags: windows-10, hid-device

We are in the process of migrating to Windows 10. We encountered an issue with the USB Barcode Scanner on
a Windows 10 system. The scanner is not working until we unplug and plug it again. Later we found that the registry EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled is set to 1 for the HID device and setting it to 0 helps us to avoid reconnecting the Barcode Scanner every time after a system reboot. Is there a way to default EnhancedPowerManagementEnabled to 0 first time when the Barcode Scanner is connected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Many registry entries are set by other registry entries at boot. Maybe your power plan is overwriting the registry key , you have to disable the USB settings in power plan.